# Simple Tables in PDFsharp - without using MigraDoc?

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I have been tasked with trying to transpose our current ITextSharp PDF Export functionality over to use PDFsharp. I am finding some similarities between the two products which is helpful however I am particularly finding it difficult to find much information on creating Tables within PDFsharp Documents...
Everywhere I look is taking me down the road of MigraDoc. I am curious to know if I am just missing a trick with PDFsharp or do I really need to get started with MigraDoc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create tables with PDFsharp you have to draw text and then draw lines around it. PDFsharp is a low-level library for creating PDF files. There are no tables (yet) in PDFsharp.

MigraDoc is a high-level document library and it is much like Word, having tables, paragraphs and handling line-breaks and page-breaks for you.

Depending on your needs either try MigraDoc or create your own table helpers for PDFsharp.

Comment: Thanks Bally - That pretty much confirms where I thought this was going. I don't have time to create my own helpers so it looks like MigraDoc is the way forward. Am I able to Create 'Sections' in Migradoc and apply them to 'Pages' in PDFSharp do you know? Or is it best to leave the two products separate?

Comment: A MigraDoc document has at least one section and that section will have as many pages as needed. You can create the PDF pages in PDFsharp, let MigraDoc draw the contents for each page and make changes as needed. If you do not have special needs, you can let MigraDoc create the PDF with all pages that are needed. In the best case you do not have to deal with PDFsharp at all when using MigraDoc to create PDF files - MigraDoc uses PDFsharp internally.

Comment: Amazing, very handy to know... Thanks for that!